# sqlite driver setup for Access on network

Tags: sqlite, ms-access, odbc

I have a sqlite3 table that I want to link to an Access 2016 application. I installed the sqlite3 driver and set up a DSN in a shared folder on a network drive so other PCs on the network can use it.

When I attempt through External Data in Access to link the table, after picking the DSN from the Windows dialog, I get the error
 *connect failed (#14) (Microsoft)[ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed IM006 0 [Microsoft] [ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConntectAttr failed (#0)*

Also, once I get this working do I need to install sqlite3.dll on each PC? Currently I only have it on the network share, which is where I'm getting the error.

Comment: The SQLite ODBC driver needs to be installed on each client machine. If you created a File DSN in a network folder then your app will need to use `FILEDSN=` (not `DSN=`) in the connection string.

Comment: You are aware how to use a non MS Access Backend? Read [Optimizing Microsoft Office Access Applications Linked to SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/administrator/bb188204(v=sql.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#understanding-dynasets) to understand how Office Access communicates with SQL Server (applies to allmost all other RDBMS (e.g SQLite) too) over ODBC. All tables need a primary key and timestamp field-

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem. It appears that there was some kind of glitch in my accdb file. I replaced it with a different copy and was able to make the odbc connection with no issues.